# i am trying to print out this simply equation, but it says float object is not callable

Tags: python

I have been trying to print out this very simple equation but I cannot figure out why it will not print?

```
fc = float(input("first cycle is "))
fp = float(input("first percent is "))

sc = float(input("second cycle is "))
sp = float(input("second percent is "))

tc = float(input("third cycle is "))
tp = float(input("third percent is "))

mem = float(input("the memory is "))

first_part = (fc * fp + (sc(1-fp)))

print(first_part)
```

It gives me the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable"

Answer (score 2):

The `*` multiplication operator cannot be omitted as it can in an algebraic equation. The interpreter thinks `sc(1-fp)` is a function call.

```
first_part = (fc * fp + (sc * (1-fp)))
```